# Elasticsearch, nested bucket inside date histogram

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm storing each `search` and `click on the search result` as the following.

```
{
  "_index": "reviewmeta_searchlog_index",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "4016313",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": 4016313,
    "created_at": "2019-03-04T09:37:56.140819+00:00",
    "search_data": {
      "query": "서대문자연사",
      "screen": "search",
      "variant_name": "a",
      "order_by": "default",
      "page": "1",
      "result_count": 760,
      "sort_by": "popular"
    },
    "click_1": 1,
    "result_count": 760,
    "user": {
      "id": 273412
    },
    "clicks": [
      {
        "review_meta": {
          "name": "서대문 자연사 박물관",
          "location": {
            "lon": 126.937755689287,
            "lat": 37.576744115598
          },
          "id": 371
        },
        "created_at": "2019-03-04T09:37:58.975258+00:00",
        "id": 1717585,
        "position": 1
      },
      {
        "review_meta": {
          "name": "서대문 자연사 박물관",
          "location": {
            "lon": 126.937755689287,
            "lat": 37.576744115598
          },
          "id": 371
        },
        "created_at": "2019-03-04T09:38:01.819918+00:00",
        "id": 1717586,
        "position": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "created_at": [
      "2019-03-04T09:37:56.140Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to get most clicked search keyword per day and using the following search.

```
 GET reviewmeta_searchlog_index/_search
 {
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs": {
       "clicks": {
          "date_histogram": {
             "field": "created_at",
            "interval": "day"
          },
          "aggs": {
             "per_query_sum": {
                "terms": {
                   "field": "search_data.query.keyword"
                },
                "aggs": {
                   "count_click": {
                      "cardinality": { "field": "clicks.id" }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Does my search look ok? (I'm not sure if `cardinality` is doing what I intend to get)

Comment: Be carrefull with jetlag, depending of your locations, you could have a gap (in this case, script could help you).

edit: i took a deeper look at your documents, can you join your mappings? Your path seems to be wrong in your querry (for exemple you dont have to put a .keyword)

Comment: You shouldnot use same name field for differents fields, not a best practice with elasticsearch (https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring#conflicting-mappings)